# Does standalone metastore 3.0 need Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I was just trying to setup Standalone Metastore 3.0, however seems like it requires also Hadoop. My understanding was that the whole point for standalone metastore that is just a service which doesn't require Hive or Hadoop. 
Thus my question is, if it's possible to run Metastore 3.0 without Hadoop?

When I try to run metastore service, getting following error :

> Cannot find hadoop installation: \$HADOOP_HOME or \$HADOOP_PREFIX must
>   be set or hadoop must be in the path

Here is the code in the bash script that checks hadoop installation:

```
# check for hadoop in the path
HADOOP_IN_PATH=`which hadoop 2>/dev/null`
if [ -f ${HADOOP_IN_PATH} ]; then
  HADOOP_DIR=`dirname "$HADOOP_IN_PATH"`/..
fi
# HADOOP_HOME env variable overrides hadoop in the path
HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME:-${HADOOP_PREFIX:-$HADOOP_DIR}}
if [ "$HADOOP_HOME" == "" ]; then
  echo "Cannot find hadoop installation: \$HADOOP_HOME or \$HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path";
  exit 4;
fi
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Where are you seeing Hadoop being a requirement? There's a section of the wiki that says "without Hive", but this means "without the rest of Hive"... There might be core Hadoop libraries used, but you should not need HDFS or YARN or MapReduce libraries

Comment: @cricket_007, basically in the bash script that starts the service is if condition that checks HADOOP classpath. As I don't have hadoop at all, it's complaining "Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path". Seems like it just wants to have a HADOOP installation. But not sure, that's why I am asking :)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2019/06/05/hive-3-standalone-metastore-presto/),

> "...while I did manage to run the Hive Standalone Metastore without
> installing hadoop, I did have to install (but not run) hadoop in order
> to use the schematool provided with hive for creating the hive RDMBS
> schema.  This is due to library dependencies."